# There is an error like this "Error: Member not found: 'fadeDuration'." on flutter 3.16.5

Tags: ios, flutter

```
Error (Xcode): ../../../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_math_fork-0.6.3+1/lib/src/widgets/selection/handle_overlay.dart:60:40: Error: Member not found: 'fadeDuration'.
```

When I update `flutter_html: ^3.0.0-beta.2` and run the application there is an error like this.

I have updated the sdk and used `flutter pub upgrade`.

Comment: What happens if you use the latest _stable_ release of ```flutter_html: ^2.2.1```?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems missed this static value from Flutter SDK.

A workaround is clone `flutter_math_fork-0.6.3+1` and replace `fadeDuration` by `Duration(milliseconds: 150)` instead of using the `TextSelectionOverlay.fadeDuration`.

The document of this value is here. [fadeDuration constant](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SelectionOverlay/fadeDuration-constant.html)